# Help on notation: $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ vs. $\mathbb{Z}_n$

Tags: number-theory, abstract-algebra, notation

I have difficulties understanding the difference between the following two notations:

- $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ (which denotes a [quotient ring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_ring)) and
- $\mathbb{Z}_n$.

Are they equivalent?

PS1: The same applies to the multiplicative counterparts:

- $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^*$
- $\mathbb{Z}_n^*$.

PS2: It can be proven that $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ is a **ﬁeld** if and only if $n$ is prime. Assuming $n$ is prime, could you compare $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ with $\text{GF}(n)$?

Comment: Yes, they are. But  $\mathbb{Z}_p$ often denoted $p$-adic integers which is not the same as  $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ at all. Some author(e.g. Rotman) also uses $\mathbb{I}_n$ denote $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: Usually I use the notation $GF(p)$ or $\mathbb F_p$ when I'm explicitly interested in the field structure. For the additive group structure I prefer $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$ or $C_p$.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It depends on the textbook/paper author, but often $\mathbf{Z}/n\mathbf{Z}$ and $\mathbf{Z}_n$ mean the same thing.

A word of caution, however: using the notation $\mathbf{Z}_n$ to mean $\mathbf{Z}/n\mathbf{Z}$ can cause confusion, because $\mathbf{Z}_p$ is also used to denote the *p-adic integers*. Thus, many mathematicians (especially number theorists) reserve the shorter notation for p-adics and use the long notation for the finite cyclic groups.

Edit: Just now saw your second question. The answer is that, indeed,  $\mathbf{Z}/p\mathbf{Z} = GF(p)$, where $p$ is prime.

Comment: For some reason, some authors and teachers think that they will scare first year undergraduates by using the quotient group/ring notation. That is the notation one should exclusively though, for the reason you describe.

Comment: I agree! Another notation which I don't often see, but which I sort of favor, is $\mathbf{C}_n$ for the cyclic group of order n. It has the same brevity as $\mathbf{Z}_n$ without the confusion. Unless $\mathbf{C}_n$ is used for something else, too...?

Comment: $C_n$ or $Z_n$ (for German zyklisch) is fine and is often used, but $\mathbb{C}_p$ is used in number theory for the completion of the algebraic closure of the field of $p$-adic numbers, so shouldn't be used in this context.

Comment: I disagree that the $\textbf{Z}/n\textbf{Z}$ notation should be used exclusively.  When dealing with direct sums of several cyclic groups (e.g. in homology computations), the $\textbf{Z}_n$ notation is much more readable.  I would also feel strange using $C_n$ for an additive cyclic group.

Comment: @Jim I am objecting to bold face. See my second comment.

Comment: Good points, all. As long as authors are explicit at the offset about what notation they are using, I guess it needn't cause any confusion. As always, context is key.

Comment: while $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$ denotes localized at $(p)$...

Answer (score 7):

If $n$ is a prime number, then $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ and $GF(n)$ are isomorphic (in fact I would simply define $GF(n)=\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ when $n$ is a prime number).

However, if $n$ is some power of a prime number, say $n=p^k$ for $k\geq 2$, then $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ and $GF(n)$ are **not** the same.

Comment: @Zev using the undefined notation $GF(n)$ that didn't feature anywhere in the question and not answering the actual question is likely to exacerbate the OP's confusion instead of clearing it up.

Comment: @Alex: The OP amended their question to also ask for a comparison of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ and $GF(n)$.

Comment: @Zev: sorry Zev, I hadn't see the edit. +1 then :-)

Comment: Thanks. As you pointed, the wording "it is said" is not good. I changed it to "it can be proven."

Comment: @Sadeq: I've removed the corresponding part of my answer, now that it is changed.

Comment: @Alex: No problem, and thanks for the +1 :)

Comment: By the way, $GF(n)$ is sometimes denoted $\mathbb{F}_n$.

Answer (score 4):

The notations are equivalent if the author has been careful enough to tell you that by $Z_n$ she means "the integers modulo $n$." If she has not been careful than you have to study the context to decide whether the author means the integers modulo $n$ or something else.

By the way, $Z/nZ$ is not just a quotient group, it's a quotient $\it ring$ (if you haven't studied rings and ideals yet, you have something to look forward to!).

Answer (score 1):

To avoid confusion that mentioned in Jeff's answer, some contemporary textbooks (like Rotman's [Advanced Modern Algebra](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0821847414)) use $\mathbb I_n$ instead of $\mathbb Z_n$. The symbol $\mathbb I$ is the first letter of **integer**.

Comment: This was mentioned in a comment to the original question. Five years ago, ten minutes after the question was posted.

Comment: @tomasz :) I only read the question and the answers!

Answer (score 1):

I very like the notation $\mathbb Z_{/n}$ to denote the ring of integers modulo $n$. This avoids ambiguities.