# Difference between $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}_p$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, ring-theory, prime-numbers

Assuming $p$ is a prime obviously, am I missing something or are both sets just $\{0, 1, \dots, p-1\}$.

I also still don't fully understand what a quotient is, so maybe that has something to do with this? Please enlighten me.

Comment: What's your definition of $\mathbb Z_p$? The notation is used for different rings, depending on context.

Comment: @Christoph i honestly am not sure, ive seen it in 2 courses, i think it vaguely means the set i mentioned above

Comment: The notation $\mathbb Z/p \mathbb Z$ is standard for integers modulo $p$, as a set one can think of it as equivalence classes $\{[0],\ldots, [p-1]\}$ or as you say, as numbers from $0$ to $p-1$ with appropriate multiplication/product. The notation $\mathbb Z_p$ has two standard meanings: one is the so called "topologists notation", $\mathbb Z_p = \mathbb Z/p \mathbb Z$. The other one refers to the $p$-adic integers. Which one you are working with depends on the context.

Comment: Personally, I try to reserve the notation $\mathbb Z_p$ for the [p-adic integers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_number) but that rule isn't universally followed.

Comment: @guidoar so is $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ just the set of all integers modulo $p$? For example, $p + 1$ is just 1 in this set?

Comment: Yes, $p+1=1$ in $\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z$, because $p=0$. Actually, this is written as $\Bbb F_p$, the finite field with $p$ elements. Here we can compute like usual, because it is a field (only a bit different, that $p=1+1+\cdot +1=0$). So it is not just "in this set", but really in a field.

Comment: @guidoar Where did you hear "topologists notation"? In my experience $\,\Bbb Z_p := \Bbb Z/p\,$ is far more common in *introductory* number theory (and discrete mathematics), i.e. in contexts where $p$-adics are not used so there is no chance of notation clash.

Comment: This term is (informally) used for example in the 'Notational Conventions' section of Brown's *Cohomology of Groups*. I remember reading it on this site a couple times too. I don't know the origin of this terminology, though (and I agree with your comment)

Comment: @BillDubuque I have just found a historical remark along the lines of this usage on Warning 0.0.5 of May and Ponto's *More Concise Algebraic Topology*.

Comment: Namely: "We warn the reader that algebraic notations in the literature
of algebraic topology have drifted over time and are quite inconsistent. The reader
may find $\mathbb Z_p$ used for either our $\mathbb Z_{(p)}$ or for our $\mathbb F_p$; the latter choice is used ubiquitously in the “early” literature, including most of the first author’s papers...."

Comment: (cont.) "...In fact, regrettably, we must warn the reader that $\mathbb Z_p$ means $\mathbb F_p$ in the book [91]. The $p$-adic integers only began to be used in algebraic topology in the 1970’s, and old habits die hard. In both the algebraic and topological literature, the ring $\mathbb Z_p$ is sometimes denoted $\widehat{\mathbb Z}_p$; we would prefer that notation as a matter of logic, but the notation $\mathbb Z_p$ has by now become quite standard".

Comment: @guidoar Interesting, thanks much for the links. In case this thread gets deleted you might want to move the comments somewhere more stable, e.g. [the linked dupe](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/43824/242), though there may be a better place.